# How to show wrapped text after hover?

Tags: html, css

There is block with long text:

```
<div>Text...</div>
```

How to show all text when usre hovers?

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will push other content out of the way so you'll need to find a design solution to get around that, but just hiding/showing the overflow will do what you want.

```css
p {
  width: 200px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

p:hover {
  overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is pure CSS solution:

```css
div>span {
  display: none;
}

div:hover>span {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Long text...
  <span>
    lorem ipsum dolor sit ames
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: I dont need show/hide, I need to show full text instead short: 'text...'

Comment: Maybe you should have a well written question instead of what you gave us.